# Find Hostname of Host from inside a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, hostname

Scenario:

I connect to VM with IP 10.1.1.1 with hostname NODE. I need to find out the IP or hostname of the host this VM is running on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely. The entire idea of a VM is that it is a shielded, emulated, environment. Although it is possible with VirtualBox to place the VM in the same network, thus allowing you to contact the host over the network, you still need to know some info about the host to find out what its ip or hostname is.

It is possible in most VM software packages to directly map shared local folders, and theoretically you could hack something to make it possible, but I don't think that's what you're after, as you're always required to do something from the host's end first.

Comment: Well the VM does is connected to the local domain, so I can log into the VM with my network credentials.

Comment: The idea was to find the host name of the host machine so I could find the server physically, since we have a little over 50 server here at work, and I wanted to forgo asking my boss which server it was :).

Comment: Just try a server you think it could be, and if its not, ask your boss. Sorry to ask, but I thought it was server xxx and I tried it but apparently it isn't. Which server was it again? Then write it down on a piece of paper that he can see and say: now I definitely will remember. :) It doesn't look silly if you say it this way.